# Hash over binary data that tolerates different sortings of binary content, C#

Tags: c#

this may be a silly question but ok.

In a C# program, I need a hash digest over a byte array which I want to compare later to the hash over another byte array (of the same size). I cannot make use of algorithms like MD5 etc. because what I need to tolerate that some segments in the binary data appear in different order.

E.g.

{ 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07 }
and
{ 00, 01, 04, 05, 02, 03, 06, 07 }

must be considered equal and produce the same hash value.

A simple solution I can think of is just to add up all byte values into one sum and further add the length of the array or so. But I'm wondering if there's something more sophisticated.
Ok I could also sort all the bytes and then take the hash, but that may be a performance killer.

Update: I expect byte array lengths of up to one MB.

Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What is the expected length of your byte array? 100 elements 100000 elements.

Comment: The expected size is up to 1 MB.
Someone downvoted my question and the status is closed now and it says that this question lacks "details or clarity". Other that the expected size info, I don't see a reason for that and I don't like this kind of paternalism. I think I'm just going to delete this question.

Answer (score 3):

Idea: Build an array (or another appropriate, serialisable collection) of 256 ints to store the number of occurrences of each byte value.  Hash this with a decent hashing function of your choice.  (O(n) performance overhead in addition to the cost of hashing.)

It will be fascinating to see what other ideas come up.

Along these lines...

```
  var b1 = new byte[8] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
  var counts1 = new int[256];
  foreach (var b in b1) count1[b]++;
  var hash1 = Hasher(counts1);
 
  var b2 = new byte[8] {6, 1, 3, 7, 0, 4, 2, 5};
  var counts2 = new int[256];
  foreach (var b in b2) count2[b]++;
  var hash2 = Hasher(counts2);
```